# Flexbox column grow not accounting for wrapped content correctly in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I put together a very simple page using a main flex container to force a footer to remain at the bottom of the page. 
It works perfectly in the major browsers, except IE11.

In IE, although it works initially, if the content inside has to wrap, the calculated size of the flexbox doesn't adjust. I've tried setting min-height, different flex basis, variations of flex grow/shrink, prefixes. Nothing seems to work.

Here, you can see it adjusting correctly before the view port is small enough to wrap the content:

[image: flex not wrapped]

And here is what happens when the page is smaller:

[image: flex wrapped]

I'm not sure what else I can try to get IE fully supported.

Here is the html code I'm testing with

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 auto">
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
        <h1>This is a long test message to test the wrapping</h1>
    </div>
    <footer style="text-align: right; flex: 0 0 auto; border-top: 1px solid grey;">
        <h4>Footer Content<h4>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [caniuse.com's listing for the flexbox module](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) IE11 is marked as "Partial support due to the number of bugs in the implementation".

Answer (score 0):

try to use min-height: 100% in html body and div contain body and footer